# Manipulating A Formula To Calculate Total Points

Tags: jquery

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/zmalter99/pen/GNPExy?editors=1010) jQuery.

```js
var $oBox = $('.outer-box');
var $gpa = $('#gpa');
var $result = $('.result').hide();

$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('.block').last().clone().children().val("").parent().appendTo($('.inner-box'));
});

$oBox.on('keyup', '.points', function() {
  $gpa.text(getTotal());
});

$oBox.on("change", ".total-points", function() {
  $gpa.text(getTotal());
  $result.is(":hidden") && $result.show();
});

function getTotal() {
  var gradeTotal = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  $(".points").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!isNaN($this.val()) && !isNaN($this.parent().find('.total-points').val())) {
      sum += parseFloat($this.val() || 0) * parseFloat($this.parent().find('.total-points').val() || 0);
      gradeTotal += parseFloat($this.val() || 0)
    }
  });
  return  (sum/gradeTotal).toFixed(2);
}

$(".btn").on("click", function () {
  
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #A00000;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.outer-box {
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: true;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.spacer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#class-name {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.assignment {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin:10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.points {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.result {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
}

#gpa {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.total-points {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#fixedbutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: solid 5px #00338A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#fixedbutton img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
</head>
<body>
  <div class='outer-box'>
    <div class='inner-box'>
      <form class='block'>
        <input type="text" class='assignment' placeholder="Assignment">
        </br>
        <input type="number" class='points' placeholder="Points">
      </br>
        <input type="number" class='total-points' placeholder="Total Points">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class='btn btn-default'>Add Grade</div>
    <div class='result'>
      <h3 id="gpa">GPA</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='spacer'></div>

</body>
```

How do I manipulate the code in jQuery and add up the total amount of points earned and then divide by the total number of points in the two inputs. Then it is displays as a result?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your code is

```
function getTotal() {
  var gradeTotal = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  $(".points").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!isNaN($this.val()) && !isNaN($this.parent().find('.total-points').val())) {
      sum += parseFloat($this.val() || 0) * parseFloat($this.parent().find('.total-points').val() || 0);
      gradeTotal += parseFloat($this.val() || 0)
    }
  });
  return  (sum/gradeTotal).toFixed(2);
}
```

So if I enter 10 for 'points' and 20 for 'total points' it does this calculation:

sum += 10 * 20

gradeTotal += 10

return 200/10  (= 20)

If I understand correctly, you actually want 10/20 = .5

That is easy to fix. 
Just change these two lines.

```
  sum += parseFloat($this.val() || 0);
  gradeTotal += parseFloat($this.parent().find('.total-points').val() || 0);
```

This will keep a cumulative score as you continue to add more grades.